# How to get list of cron tasks?

Tags: cron

Drupal 6 possible noob question. Is there a way to get a list of cron tasks from the Drupal 6 Admin? I am a themer for the site. The original dev is long gone. Everyone complains of slowness and 500.shtml errors. I looked in the log and noticed that these are most often associated with a cron task that runs hourly. But I can't see what those jobs are. Once I get the list is there also a way to disable unneeded tasks from within Drupal?

I'm running Windows on my client machine. I don't have DRUSH.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you by chance happen to have Elysia Cron installed, you may be able to get a good enough idea through its admin interface, otherwise you basically will have to look through your modules' source code and look for `hook_cron()`, eg, `function MODULENAME_cron()' and then see what's happening in each.

Comment: Try this module. https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron. The Ultimate Cron handling for Drupal. Runs cron jobs individually in parallel using configurable rules, pool management and load balancing. It is like Elysia cron in D7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have Elysia Cron installed, and from a purely debugging standpoint, if you want or need to see what module's cron is running, as well as how long it is taking to run, you can **TEMPORARILY** edit `includes/common.inc`'s `drupal_cron_run()` function like so...

```
// Iterate through the modules calling their cron handlers (if any):
// module_invoke_all('cron'); // watchdog how long each hook takes now...

$details='';
foreach (module_implements('cron') as $module) {
  $start=microtime(TRUE);
  $function = $module . '_cron';
  $function();
  $finish=microtime(TRUE);
  $duration=$finish - $start;
  $details.='<pre>' . $module . ': ' . $duration . ' seconds</pre>';
}

// Record cron time
variable_set('cron_last', time());
watchdog('cron', 'Cron run completed.' . $details, array(), WATCHDOG_NOTICE); // . in $details here :)
```

eg, comment out the `module_invoke_all()` and instead loop through via `module_implements()` and log how long each individual cron run takes.

Comment: Can I just add the Elysia module?

I looked in the cPanel and the cron from Drupal is executing hourly. Will Elysia give me details on what -Drupal- is doineg every hour? All I see is a wget. A lot of the 500 errors we get occur right after this.

Comment: Does this trick apply for D7 too?

Comment: D7 does it a bit differently but sure, you could add some `microtime()`s to its version temporarily as well.

Answer (score 8):

Or simple use

```
drush ev 'var_dump(module_implements("cron"))'
```

For list the cron job that exists.

Comment: Hello and welcome. This provide an answer, but is now formatted in a way that makes it look like a comment. Could you please edit it to make it look like a standalone entity and not a voice in conversation? This is Q&A site and not a forum, after all :)

Comment: This only tells you which modules have a cron installed, which is a nice start, but it'd be nicer to see exactly what each individual task was.

Comment: This returned an error while having Drupal 10 installed locally with DDEV:
```Error: Call to undefined function module_implements() in eval() (line 1 of /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/PhpCommands.php(32) : eval()'d code).```

Answer (score 5):

For Drupal 8/9, you can simply use the following command:

```
drush php-eval 'var_dump(\Drupal::moduleHandler()->getImplementations("cron"))'
```

Comment: This returned an error while having Drupal 10 installed locally with DDEV:
```Error: Call to undefined function module_implements() in eval() (line 1 of /var/www/html/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/PhpCommands.php(32) : eval()'d code).```